# GAE User + OpenId + Oauth2 Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, openid

I have a GAE application.
I need to:

1. The user gets access to the application
2. The application detects if the user is authenticated
3. If not, redirect to google account login page
4. The user logs in
5. Google Account redirects to my application
6. The application checks if that user is registered in the application
7. If yes, the application asks for the user if he agrees that latter to get private info  gmail, contacts, (etc.) from his google account

My problem is I am really lost on doing steps 3, 5 and 7. I think I don't even need OpenId to do so. I have read google code pages on Federated Login, OpenId, OAuth2 and User API, but I can't find a way to mix them all (what to put in client side? What to put in server side? Do I need to create a special Servlet? Can I use RPC async services? Do I need to write a http request client side and ask for a special servlet? Etc...). As I am using GAE I don't have any JSPs files but one entry point html page which contains the least minimum html required.

I would be really happy if someone could give me links to source code (Java) to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about someone's Google ID in general?  Or only from people with Google apps accounts from your domain?

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-oauth.html

Comment: @Dave I want google Id in general, the application should determine if the user is connected and if not redirect to google accounts. I am not using any jsp file but just one HTML file (GAE) which I want the least code in it. I know how to use OAuth to access Gdata. I want to know what to put in my EntryPoint class, and what to write in the server side.

Answer (score 2):

I too had a mix of OpenID and OAuth logins with google app engine and you can mix. At the end in my case I settled on just Google and Facebook as providers and Google login is builtin and Facebook login is OAuth. It's true there should be a more convenient way to "add an OAuth provider" and add yourself as an OAuth provider same way we add Twitter and Facebook however at this stage is more or less programming it yourself and following the OAuth 2.0 login / logout flow independent of which implementation you do (Java, python, PHP..) since the OAuth 2.0 flow is the same regardless of which language you use for example OAuth with Facebook which I use with GAE:

[image]

You might want to read through the [OAuth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) page for a large provider, Facebook, to see how you should do the authentication flow.

Comment: How are you getting the User after they login? With Google, we would use UserService to retrieve the User object. What do you use here to store the user in memory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  throws IOException     
{  

  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  User user = userService.getCurrentUser();        
  if (user != null) //checks if USER is logged in or not
  {            
       //if USER is logged in this code will execute or you can redirect user to another page
       resp.setContentType("text/plain"); 
       resp.getWriter().println("Hello, " + user.getNickname());
  } else {           //if USER is null, which means its not logged in then this code will execute. 
        String returnURL = "/home.jsp";
        resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(returnURL));
        //createLoginURL method will provide the Google Login URL to sendRedirect method
        //after user log in on the Google login page, the user will be redirected to the URL in returnURL variable

   }   
}
```

Source = http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers.html

Comment: I have already read this page, but my problem is I don't use any jsp file. As a GAE application, there is just one HTML file in which I want to put the least code possible.

Comment: I want to know what to put in my EntryPoint class, and what to write in the server side.

Comment: you cannot put any JAVA code in HTML file. You need to create atleast one JSP or JAVA Servlet which will be the entry point of your GAE application and put this above code in it. This code is your entry point if you want to authenticate users before allowing them to use your application.

Comment: @user1098001, what is your EntryPoint class?  Does it extend any objects?  Is it a servlet, or a filter?

Comment: I know that I don't put any java in HTML. My entry point implements EntryPoint. I don't understand why it has to be a servlet as the EntryPoint class is in the client side

Comment: @user1098001 you are right. i just gave example to use jsp or servlet as entrypoint. you can use any other option as well. I use filter to implement user authentication.

Comment: @KashifKhan - Do you have an example that would use Facebook or another provider?  Thanks!

Comment: @jmort253 read this page http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html. it shows openid authentication through google, yahoo, myspace, aol, myopenid on google app engine. example is provided in both python and java.